# What is the advantage of using Python Virtualbox API?

Tags: python, virtualbox, xpcom

what is the advantage of using  a python virtualbox API instead of using XPCOM?

Answer (score 9):

The advantage is that pyvb is lot easier to work with.

On the contrary the documentation for the python API of XPCOM doesn't exist, and the API is not pythonic at all. You can't do introspection to find methods/attributes of an object, etc. So you have to check the C++ source to find how it works or some python scripts already written (like [vboxshell.py](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Frontends/VBoxShell/vboxshell.py) and [VBoxWebSrv.py](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/source/browse/trunk/VBoxWebSrv.py)).

On the other hand pyvb is really just python wrapper that call VirtuaBoxManager on the command line. I don't know if it's a real disadvantage or not?

Answer (score 5):

I would generally recommend against either one. If you need to use virtualization programmatically, take a look at libvirt, which gives you cross platform and cross hypervisor support; which lets you do kvm/xen/vz/vmware later on.

That said, the SOAP api is using two extra abstraction layers (the client and server side of the HTTP transaction), which is pretty clearly then just calling the XPCOM interface.

If you need local host only support, use XPCOM. The extra indirection of libvirt/SOAP doesn't help you.
If you need to access virtualbox on a various hosts across multiple client machines, use SOAP or libvirt
If you want cross platform support, or to run your code on Linux, use libvirt.

Answer (score 1):

From sun's site on [VirtualBox python APIs](http://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/python_api_to_the_virtualbox):

> SOAP allows to control remote VMs **over
> HTTP**, while XPCOM is much **more
> high-performing** and exposes certain
> functionality not available with SOAP.
>
> They use very different technologies
> (SOAP is procedural, while XPCOM is
> OOP), but as it is ultimately API to
> the same functionality of the
> VirtualBox, we kept in bindings
> original semantics, so other that
> connection establishment, code could
> be written in such a way that people
> may not care what communication
> channel with VirtualBox instance is
> used.

From that article, I'm having trouble seeing the difference between "python virtualbox API" and "XPCOM". Could you provide a link to the API you're thinking of?

Comment: pyvb (i.e python virtualbox )

the documentation is in the link

 http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb